# Golang RabbitMQ receiving only messages sent before start of the program

Tags: go, rabbitmq, runtime, channel, goroutine

I am trying to get rabbitmq message from sent from sender service. And here I'm implementing receiving parts.

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "rabbit/bookingservice/listener"
    "rabbit/bookingservice/rest"
    "rabbit/lib/configuration"
    msgqueue_amqp "rabbit/lib/msgqueue/amqp"
    "rabbit/lib/persistence/dblayer"

    "github.com/streadway/amqp"
)

func main() {
    confPath := flag.String("config", "./configuration/config.json", "path to config file")
    flag.Parse()
    config, _ := configuration.ExtractConfiguration(*confPath)

    fmt.Println("config.AMQPMessageBroker: ", config.AMQPMessageBroker)
    fmt.Println("config.DBConnection: ", config.DBConnection)

    dbhandler, err := dblayer.NewPersistenceLayer(config.Databasetype, config.DBConnection)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    conn, err := amqp.Dial(config.AMQPMessageBroker)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    eventListener, err := msgqueue_amqp.NewAMQPEventListner(conn, "events", "booking")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    eventEmitter, err := msgqueue_amqp.NewAMQPEventEmitter(conn, "events")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    processor := &listener.EventProcessor{EventListener: eventListener, Database: dbhandler}

    go processor.ProcessEvents()

    rest.ServeAPI("0.0.0.0:8282", dbhandler, eventEmitter)
}
```

Without go, the program will block here so i implemented message processing function that handles message coming from specified queeue with go routine

```
package listener

import (
    "log"
    "rabbit/contracts"
    "rabbit/lib/msgqueue"
    "rabbit/lib/persistence"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
)

type EventProcessor struct {
    EventListener msgqueue.EventListener
    Database      persistence.DatabaseHandler
}

func (p *EventProcessor) ProcessEvents() error {
    log.Println("Listening to events...")

    received, errors, err := p.EventListener.Listen("eventCreated")

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    //defer close(received)
    //defer close(errors)

    for {
        select {
        case evt := <-received:
            p.handleEvent(evt)
            // if err := p.handleEvent(evt); err != nil {
            //  log.Printf("Error processing event: %s", err)
            // }
        case err := <-errors:
            log.Printf("Received error while consuming msg: %s", err)
        }
    }
}

func (p *EventProcessor) handleEvent(event msgqueue.Event) {
    switch e := event.(type) {
    case *contracts.EventCreatedEvent:
        log.Printf("event %s created: %s", e.ID, e)
        id, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(e.ID)
        id2, err2 := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(e.LocationID)
        if err != nil || err2 != nil {
            log.Printf("Error parsing ObjectID: %v", err)
            // Handle the error as needed
        } else {
            id, _, err := p.Database.AddEvent4Booking(persistence.Event{ID: id, Location: persistence.Location{ID: id2}})
            log.Printf("id created: %s", id)
            if err != nil {
                log.Printf(`{error: Error occured while persisting event %s}`, err)
                return
            }
        }
    case *contracts.LocationCreatedEvent:
        log.Printf("location %s created: %v", e.ID, e)
        id, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(e.ID)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Error parsing ObjectID: %v", err)
            // Handle the error as needed
        } else {
            p.Database.AddLocation(persistence.Location{ID: id})
        }
    default:
        log.Printf("unknown event type: %t", e)
    }
}
```

Listen function used here is implemented using amqp as below

```
package amqp

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "rabbit/contracts"
    "rabbit/lib/msgqueue"

    "github.com/streadway/amqp"
)

type amqpEventListener struct {
    connection *amqp.Connection
    queue      string
    exchange   string
    //mapper     msgqueue.EventMapper
}

func NewAMQPEventListner(conn *amqp.Connection, exchange string, queue string) (msgqueue.EventListener, error) {
    listener := &amqpEventListener{
        connection: conn,
        queue:      queue,
        exchange:   exchange,
        //mapper:     msgqueue.NewEventMapper(),
    }
    err := listener.setup()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return listener, nil
}
func (a *amqpEventListener) setup() error {
    channel, err := a.connection.Channel()
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }
    defer channel.Close()
    err = channel.ExchangeDeclare(a.exchange, "topic", true, false, false, false, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    _, err = channel.QueueDeclare(a.queue, true, false, false, false, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("could not declare queue %s: %s", a.queue, err)
    }
    return nil
}

func (a *amqpEventListener) Listen(eventNames ...string) (<-chan msgqueue.Event, <-chan error, error) {
    channel, err := a.connection.Channel()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }

    defer channel.Close()
    for _, eventName := range eventNames {
        //if err := channel.QueueBind(a.queue, eventName, "events", false, nil); err != nil {
        // Create binding between queue and exchange for each listened event type
        if err := channel.QueueBind(a.queue, eventName, a.exchange, false, nil); err != nil {
            return nil, nil, err
        }
    }

    msgs, err := channel.Consume(a.queue, "", false, false, false, false, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
    events := make(chan msgqueue.Event, 1)
    errors := make(chan error)

    go func() {
        //defer close(events)
        //defer close(errors)
        for msg := range msgs {
            rawEventName, ok := msg.Headers["x-event-name"]
            if !ok {
                errors <- fmt.Errorf("msg did not contain x-event-name header")
                msg.Nack(false, false)
                continue
            }
            eventName, ok := rawEventName.(string)
            if !ok {
                errors <- fmt.Errorf("x-event-name header is not a string, but %t", rawEventName)
                msg.Nack(false, false)
                continue
            }

            var event msgqueue.Event
            switch eventName {
            case "eventCreated":
                event = new(contracts.EventCreatedEvent)
            case "locationCreated":
                event = &contracts.LocationCreatedEvent{}
            case "eventBooked":
                event = &contracts.EventBookedEvent{}
            default:
                errors <- fmt.Errorf("=event type %s is unknown", eventName)
            }
            err := json.Unmarshal(msg.Body, event)
            if err != nil {
                errors <- err
                continue
            }
            events <- event
            msg.Ack(false)
        }
    }()
    return events, errors, nil

}
```

So in Listen function I'm returning processing message loop inside go routine here is so that I first return the events channels to the caller the function immediately and process further implementation there.

The problem is when I implement main function here with main function in event sending program, I can check inside booking queue message is being queued up but neither log.Printf("event %s created: %s", e.ID, e) part is being logged (since I'm testing with contracts.EventCreatedEvent type message) nor it is being inserted to db in id, _, err := p.Database.AddEvent4Booking(persistence.Event{ID: id, Location: persistence.Location{ID: id2}}).
But then when i quit main function above and rerun, then i can see

```
2024/01/07 03:43:57 Listening to events...
2024/01/07 03:43:57 Test Listen
2024/01/07 03:43:57 event 65999d182bcc52741d5d5034 created: &{65999d182bcc52741d5d5034 My festa22 65999d182bcc52741d5d5035 1970-08-23 12:28:24 +0900 KST 1970-08-23 12:28:28 +0900 KST}
2024/01/07 03:43:57 id created: 65999d182bcc52741d5d5034
```

and also check relevant data is inserted into db. But why only message already queued up before running main is being proccessed here? received, errors, err := p.EventListener.Listen("eventCreated") . What I want is I also want to process message that is sent after I run this main function. I tried to wrap my head around this but could not figure out. If anyone could help me solve this, it would be very appreciated!

Comment: `github.com/streadway/amqp` is not actively maintained. 
please use `https://github.com/rabbitmq/amqp091-go` instead.